# Elasticsearch autocomplete with AngularJS typeahead

Tags: html, angularjs

Building an autocomplete feature using Elasticsearch and AngularJS UI bootstrap typeahead. Nearly finished but I'm having trouble getting the results to display in the dropdown.

What currently appears in the dropdown when I press the letter a and I know there are suggestions for that letter is:

```
[object Object]
```

This is my controller code

```
$scope.getSuggestions = function(query) {
$scope.isSearching = true;
return searchService.getSuggestions(query).then(function(es_return){
    var phrases;
    var phrases = es_return.hits.hits;
    return $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = phrases;
    $scope.isSearching = false;
  });
};
```

And this is my html form

```
<form ng-submit="search()" class="form-horizontal col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="hp-search-form">
```

I'm using an ES `match_phrase_prefix` query coupled with a `Shingles` analyzer which is working nicely - getting expected results in Sense. If I go to the Sense plugin for ES, I get many responses back when typing "a", so I know the ES part of this working. Where am I going wrong with UI bootstrap typeahead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your approach, considering the following lines of code:

```
return $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = phrases;
$scope.isSearching = false;
```

- The first line above will have the `phrases` as an array, so you will get `[object Object]` as the output. Replace it using `phrases[0]` or check your console for what's it returning.
- The second line will **never** be executed as it returns the control to the caller before it executes. That's an orphaned instruction.

So change your code to:

```
$scope.isSearching = false;
return $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = phrases[0]; // Verify this with console.
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and the dropdown no longer displays. The suggestions are there (I checked console) but now even the dropdown no longer displays....

Comment: @user3125823 What's there in the `phrases`? That's the problem I believe. Revert back the code, and see what's there in `phrases`? `console.log(phrases)` or something?

Comment: Lemme know what's there in it so that we can get the desired result based on that.

Comment: please see UPDATE above - getting closer I hope

Comment: Instead of `console.log()` try `console.dir()`, please?

Comment: @user3125823 Why not use [AngularJS wrapper for Select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2)?

Comment: why do you think the suggestions show vertically? As soon as I get your reply, I'll accept your answer - you've been pretty helpful

Comment: @user3125823 May be each and every character is made as an array?